# How can I get the status code from an HTTP error in Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

This may seem stupid, but I'm trying to get the error data when a request fails in Axios.

```js
axios
  .get('foo.example')
  .then((response) => {})
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error); //Logs a string: Error: Request failed with status code 404
  });
```

Instead of the string, is it possible to get an object with perhaps the status code and content? For example:

```
Object = {status: 404, reason: 'Not found', body: '404 Not found'}
```

Answer (score 1074, accepted):

What you see is the string returned by the `toString` method of the `error` object. (`error` is not a string.)

If a response has been received from the server, the `error` object will contain the `response` property:

```
axios.get('/foo')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain the magic behind it automtatically turning into a string if I don't refer to the `response` property?

Comment: `console.log` uses the `toString` method to format `Error` objects. It has nothing to do with referring to the  `response` property.

Comment: I'm still confused, is this spesific to error objects or? If I console.log an object, I get the object, not a string.

Comment: It depends on implementation. For example, node.js implementation of `console.log` [handles](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L430) `Error` objects as a special case. I cannot say how exactly it's implemented in browsers, but if you call `console.log({ foo: 'bar' });` and `console.log(new Error('foo'));` in the Chrome DevTools Console, you will see that the results look different.

Comment: Must be a native thing then. It's still strange though.

Comment: Will this work for status codes 50x ?? That is, if server is completely down ?

Comment: What about errors like 404? response is undefined in that case.

Comment: Late to the party, but FWIW `console.dir` will print the object and its properties

Comment: As ´console.log(obj)´ usually returns the object to the console, this is confusing. But hey, thanks for the solution - `msg = axiosError.response.data` worked like a charm within my response interceptor!

Comment: With 401 errors the response property is `undefined`.

Comment: You can do `console.dir` instead of `console.log` in Chrome to see the "inner" stucture of the error. This is the same trick that works with DOM elements -- it shows everything as object, instead of a "quick and pretty" (but sometimes misleading) representation.

Comment: error object does not contain response object for non 200 errors.

Comment: Solved my problem but isn't it weird? Can anyone explain that?

Comment: @Sebi2020 - it does for me.

Comment: I am getting cant get status from undefined (referring to the response object as being undefined). Solved by saying error.status instead.

Comment: I was mistaken.
I was getting error.response as undefined. It was because i had my interceptor setup wrong.
.use must return the response and onrejected must return Promise.reject(error)

Comment: it is showing err.response undefined

Answer (score 75):

With TypeScript, it is easy to find what you want with the right type.

This makes everything easier because you can get all the properties of the type with autocomplete, so you can know the proper structure of your response and error.

```
import { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from 'axios'

axios.get('foo.example')
  .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
    // Handle response
  })
  .catch((reason: AxiosError) => {
    if (reason.response!.status === 400) {
      // Handle 400
    } else {
      // Handle else
    }
    console.log(reason.message)
  })
```

Also, you can pass a parameter to both types to tell what are you expecting inside `response.data` like so:

```
import { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from 'axios'
axios.get('foo.example')
  .then((response: AxiosResponse<{user:{name:string}}>) => {
    // Handle response
  })
  .catch((reason: AxiosError<{additionalInfo:string}>) => {
    if (reason.response!.status === 400) {
      // Handle 400
    } else {
      // Handle else
    }
    console.log(reason.message)
  })
```

Comment: I'm trying to get my team to switch over to Typescript for THIS kind of clarity.

Comment: this makes everything easier because you can get all the properties of the type with intellisense, so you can know the proper structure of your response and error

Comment: I don't think the non-null assertion here (on the line `if (reason.response!.status ...)`) is safe—if you get a 0 status code (e.g. network died before a response was returned), `reason.response` will be `undefined` and you'll get a TypeError there.

Answer (score 28):

As @Nick said, the results you see when you `console.log` a JavaScript `Error` object depend on the exact implementation of `console.log`, which varies and (imo) makes checking errors incredibly annoying.

If you'd like to see the full `Error` object and all the information it carries bypassing the `toString()` method, you could just use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
axios.get('/foo')
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
  });
```

Comment: Currently, this does not work. It does not show the contents inside of error.response.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(error)` is a potential candidate for throwing `Circular dependency` error in this case.

Answer (score 22):

There is a new option called `validateStatus` in request config. You can use it to specify to not throw exceptions if status < 100 or status > 300 (default behavior). Example:

```
const {status} = axios.get('foo.example', {validateStatus: () => true})
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the spread operator (`...`) to force it into a new object like this:

```
axios.get('foo.example')
    .then((response) => {})
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log({...error})
})
```

Be aware: this will not be an instance of Error.

Answer (score 12):

I am using this interceptors to get the error response.

```
const HttpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: env.baseUrl,
});

HttpClient.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  return Promise.resolve({ error });
});
```

Comment: What is the specific advantage when using interceptors?

Comment: You can intercept requests or responses before they are handled by then or catch.

Answer (score 10):

In order to get the http status code returned from the server, you can add `validateStatus: status => true` to axios options:

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/users/login',
    data: { username, password },
    validateStatus: () => true
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.status);
});
```

This way, every http response resolves the promise returned from axios.

https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Answer (score 9):

**Whole error can only be shown using error.response like that :**

```
axios.get('url').catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
// console.log(name);
setLoading(true);
createCategory({ name }, user.token)
  .then((res) => {
   // console.log("res",res);
    setLoading(false);
    setName("");
    toast.success(`"${res.data.name}" is created`);
    loadCategories();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    setLoading(false);
    if (err.response.status === 400) toast.error(err.response.data);//explained in GD
  });
```

};

See the console log then you will understand clearly

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Axios. get('foo.example')
.then((response) => {})
.catch((error) => {
    if(error. response){
       console.log(error. response. data)
       console.log(error. response. status);

      }
})
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: I think I understand how this code works... its checking if response exist, then console.log... I think this is a good solution.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained why this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements the other answers. In fact, it's essentially identical to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

With Axios

```
    post('/stores', body).then((res) => {

        notifyInfo("Store Created Successfully")
        GetStore()
    }).catch(function (error) {

        if (error.status === 409) {
            notifyError("Duplicate Location ID, Please Add another one")
        } else {
            notifyError(error.data.detail)
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed pretty weird that fetching only **error** does not return an object. While returning **error.response** gives you access to most feedback stuff you need.

I ended up using this:

```
axios.get(...).catch( error => { return Promise.reject(error.response.data.error); });
```

Which gives strictly the stuff I need: status code (404) and the text-message of the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, try to use  `"axios": "0.13.1"`

https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/378

I had the same problem so I ended up using  `"axios": "0.12.0"`. It works fine for me.

Comment: This is not the same issue I'm having, there's not even an object involved when I log `error`

Answer (score 1):

You can put the error into an object and log the object, like this:

```
axios.get('foo.example')
    .then((response) => {})
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log({error}) // this will log an empty object with an error property
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

An Axios Error has a lot of information, but if you do a regular `console.log(error)` you would just get a 'string message' generic error like: *"Error: Request failed with status code XXX"*

A solution to handle Axios Error and other errors is:

```
axios.get('foo.example')
    .then((response) => {//...})
    .catch (error: any) {
        let errorResponse: any;

        // it is an AxiosError
        if (error?.isAxiosError) {
            const axiosError = error as AxiosError;
            errorResponse = axiosError.response; //all the info here
        } else {
            errorResponse = error; // it is not an AxiosError
        }

        console.log(errorResponse);
        throw errorResponse;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's my code: Work for me

```
 var jsonData = request.body;
    var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

    // message_body = {
    //   "phone": "5511995001920",
    //   "body": "WhatsApp API on chat-api.com works good"
    // }

    axios.post(whatsapp_url, jsonParsed,validateStatus = true)
    .then((res) => {
      // console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

            console.log(res.data)
        console.log(res.status);

        // var jsonData = res.body;
        // var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

        response.json("ok")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
        response.json("error")
    })
```