# How to display response error message with axios

Tags: javascript, httpresponse, axios

Been looking to achieve this few months now but now it's needed. I need to display the error message, set on server, about what went wrong:

Sever endpoint

```
abort(406, 'Foo bar!')
```

Web:

```
[...]
 .catch(e => {
  console.log(e.response.data) // does not work
 })
```

In chrome dev tools, under preview, I see the message `Foo bar!`. How to get this message on my console log?

This endpoint will have different `abort` messages based on actions so I do not want to set a static error message on web for the error.

Chrome dev tools message:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the status code from an http error in Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153080/how-can-i-get-the-status-code-from-an-http-error-in-axios)

Answer (score 21):

This should work : console.log(e.response.data.message). I think this is what you looking for.

This is for this type of request:

```
axios.post(
    url,
    {},
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data.message);
    });
```

Comment: Nothing returns the message I set: `Foo bar!`

Comment: Did you try with e.message?

Comment: I got `Request failed with status code 406`. Im using Laravel if that makes a different. But Chrome dev tools show the actual message `Foo bar!`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145957/discussion-between-matija-zupancic-and-sylar).

Comment: Line 4 Missing '{'

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response)
                console.log(error.response?.data?.message)
                return 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this problem. i created an axios instance, the responseType is 'json', 
`axios.create({
    ...
    responseType: 'json'
})`

response type is not json，so i can't got it. remove this property can solve this problem

Comment: can you elaborate why removing the responseType can solve this problem?

Comment: The response content-type returned by the server is not json, is 'arraybuffer', 'blob', 'document', or other ，i set json，so can not get other type