# How can axios get the status code in .catch()?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, axios

In the [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) document:

```
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  });
```

we know we can catch the `error` in the `.catch()` method.

But when I use the Django-Rest-Framework as the backend API provider. it only provide the data, there is no status in it:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You see the `error`:

```
{username: ["A user with that username already exists."]}
```

but in the browser, we can know the status code:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

Before asking this question, I have read [How can I get the status code from an http error in Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153080/how-can-i-get-the-status-code-from-an-http-error-in-axios)
this post.

But the post seems different with mine.

---

**EDIT-1**

In my Django-Rest-Framework project:

the view:

```
class UserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

the serializer:

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    user register
    """
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'wechat_num',
            'password',
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password":{"write_only":True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username=validated_data.pop('username')
        wechat_num = validated_data.pop('wechat_num')
        password=validated_data.pop('password')

        user_obj = User(
            username=username,
            wechat_num=wechat_num,
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()
        group=getOrCreateGroupByName(USER_GROUP_CHOICES.User)
        user_obj.groups.add(group)

        return validated_data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find in the `interceptors` configuration:

```
Axios.interceptors.response.use(
  res => {

    return res;
  },
  error => {

    return Promise.reject(error.response.data)
  }
);
```

I was return the `error.response.data` directly, I could configure it to `error.response`, or `error`.

if I configure the `error.response`, then in the `.catch()` I can console like bellow:

```
console.log(response.data);
console.log(response.status);
console.log(response.headers);
```