# How do I show message on 403 client side if the email fails to send?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, promise

I am trying to show alert message when the email sends or gets failed. If it fails, I'm getting 403 from the backend. But not sure how do I show it here in client-side. If success, I get a 200. Right now, in the case of failure, if I `console.log(res)`(as you can see below), it shows

`res is not defined`

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403`

And in network tab, I get the response. That's alright.

I just want to show it here client side in my react component.

```js
  handleClick = (id) => {
    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/send-post/${id}`)
      .then((res) =>
        console.log(res),
        res.status === 200 ? alert("Email sent"): null
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err) {
          return alert("Sorry, Something went wrong")
        }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error status is in `err.response.status`.

Modify

```
if (err) {
          return alert("Sorry, Something went wrong")
        }
```

with

```
if (err) {
          return alert("Sorry, Something went wrong. Status "+ err.response.status)
        }
```

For reference, you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/39153411/12680971

Comment: Yes. it's in catch block. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma `,` after `console.log` call.

Do next:

```
.then(res => {
   console.log(res);
   res.status === 200 && alert("Email sent");
})
```

Or another variant:

```
.then(res =>
   console.log(res) ||
   res.status === 200 ? alert("Email sent") : null
)
```