# Checking if a 404 error was returned in the axios library

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

A 404 error is not returned directly as `res.status` in the `axios` library but thrown in the catch as an error.
My question is now can I somehow query in the catch, which number the error has?

```
.catch(error => {
if(error.status === 404)     
// do something     
}
```

Or how can I use the axios library to query if it is a 404 error or not?

```
const handleLogin = () => {
        axios.post('localhost:4000', {"email":`${email}`, "password":`${password}`})
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
            console.log(res.status);
            if(res.status === 200) {
              setValidationNoExist(true);
               history.push({
                pathname: '/app',
                state: {
                  email: email,
                  name: password,
                },
              })
            }
            else if(res.status === 203) {
              setValidationWrong(false);
            }
            else if(res.status === 404) {
                setValidationPending(false);
            }
             else if(res.status === 204) {
                setValidationNoExist(false);
              }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            setValidationNoExist(false);
        })
       };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the status code from an http error in Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153080/how-can-i-get-the-status-code-from-an-http-error-in-axios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors

can you check if `error.response.status` gives you the value you need in your catch block.