# Spring Boot Can't Handle HTTP Errors In My Frontend(React)

Tags: spring, typescript, spring-boot, rest, axios

I use Axios.

So whenever I use ResponseEntity in Spring Boot to return an error, I can't seem to handle it in my frontend. Instead of getting a proper response from the server, I just get an error that I can't even use.

This is how a positive ResponseEnity is (literally just `ResponseEntity.ok(stuff)` ):

```
{data: 'Success', status: 200, statusText: '', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

Where I get the actual data I can use, instead of getting this whenever the status code isn't positive ->

This is what I get when I check the console when I send an error ResponseEntity:

```
xhr.js:210 POST http://{ip}/api/auth/login 403
```

And I tried to log the error just to see what I get. This is the response:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

This is how the login processing looks in my backend:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<?> doLogin(){
    /*Imagine it does all the authentication and then throws a 401 error*/
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .body("Error Message");
}
```

And this is how it's handled in my frontend:

```
  if (request.type === AuthType.LOGIN) {
  const { email, password } = request.data;
    UserAuthService.login(request.data).then(res => console.log(res));
    /*Ideally this is where I'd check for a few HTTP error status codes and act accordingly*/
}
```

I send the POST request and handle the response. Again, if the code returns 200 OK or any other positive number, then I would be able to use the response data as intended.

Am I missing something?

Just in case here's my Axios instance:

```
export default axios.create({
      baseURL: `${url}`,
      headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      Authorization: axiosHeader(),
    }
  });
```

Which I just import and use whenever I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was embarrassing.

[How can I get the status code from an HTTP error in Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153080/how-can-i-get-the-status-code-from-an-http-error-in-axios)

> If a response has been received from the server, the error object will
> contain the response property.

```
 axios.post("/foo").catch((err) => {
    if (err.response) {
      console.log(err.response.data);
      console.log(err.response.status);
      console.log(err.response.headers);
    }
  });
```