# how can I get status code when I get an erroruse axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to get an object when the HTTP request failed.
something like this

`Object = {status: 404, reason: 'Not found', body: '404 Not found'}`

I have read [How can I get the status code from an HTTP error in Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153080/how-can-i-get-the-status-code-from-an-http-error-in-axios),But It does not work for me.

This is the JS code,

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
    url:'https://www.icofont.cn//sd',
    method:'GET',
})
.then(response=>{
    console.log(response.status);
})
.catch(error=>{
    
    console.log(error.response.data);
    console.log(error.response.status);
    console.log(error.response.headers);
})
```

I always get an `undefined` of the `error.response`.So I get an error. I can get an error object. How can I extract `404 Not found` from this object?

Comment: Start off by just doing one console.log(error) to see if you’re getting an error object to begin with. If nothing is coming back, that’ll be why you’re currently getting undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assuming the error is returned in the response. It could also be in the request (e.g. while connecting to the server before making the request). I addded `console.log(error)` and found that on my computer the error is in the request:

```
AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 38.238.92.52:443
    at AxiosError.from (/run/user/1000/test123/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:725:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (/run/user/1000/test123/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2467:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (/run/user/1000/test123/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  port: 443,
  address: '38.238.92.52',
  syscall: 'connect',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: -111,
  config: {
[...]
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
[...]
  },
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 38.238.92.52:443
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '38.238.92.52',
    port: 443
  }
}
/run/user/1000/test123/test.js:11
    console.log(error.response.data);
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at /run/user/1000/test123/test.js:11:32
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.10.0
```

The server you are connecting to does not seem to support HTTPS. It can only be connected to if `https://www.icofont.cn//sd` is changed to `http://www.icofont.cn//sd`, and then the 404 comes out.

Instead of assuming the error is in the response or request, it should be checked for. [The official example explains this](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors).

Your fixed example will look like the following:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
    url:'http://www.icofont.cn//sd',
    method:'GET',
})
.then(response=>{
    console.log(response.status);
})
.catch(error=>{
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
})
```